# Can't access ./apache2.conf ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I can't configure `./apache2.conf`:

```
root@Xymon:/etc/apache2# ls -lid /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
2359738 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mar 12 13:56 /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
root@Xymon:/etc/apache2# dir
apache2.conf  conf-available  conf.d  conf-enabled  envvars  magic  mods-available  mods-enabled  ports.conf  sites-available  sites-enabled
root@Xymon:/etc/apache2# ./apache2.conf
bash: ./apache2.conf: Permission denied
root@Xymon:/etc/apache2# su ./apache2.conf
No passwd entry for user './apache2.conf'
root@Xymon:/etc/apache2# ???????
```

Comment: It's a file to be edited. Why are you trying to run it?

Comment: apache2.conf is a configuration file and not a executable. You might want to check out this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps

Comment: hey. i want configure <i>apache</i> server for <i>xymon</i> server. Because i don't see the page on my servers IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to edit `apache2.conf` you'll need to use some sort of text editor. Nano is a good basic text editor, which ships as standard with Ubuntu.

So enter:

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then make your edits. When you want to save edits, press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>X</kbd>  To save and exit.

After editing the Apache configuration file, it's always a good idea to issue:

```
service apache2 reload
```

This will reload the configuration file, and should alert you to any syntax errors.